# Check if last typed character was space

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I check inside my ng-change function if last typed character was a space?
ng-trim must be set to true.

I tired go to my last typed char by

```
myStr.substr(myStr.length - 1)
```

but when I was compared this to " " or something else it didn't work. I have to increment a counter when last character is a space, but I can't wait for another one.

**EDIT:**
I tired to count spaces, using ng-trim (so it isn't possible), so answers for this question are good when ng-trim is set to default - true.

Comment: do it on ng-keypress

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the text value ends with white space by the following regular-expression:
 `/\s$/`

`/\s$/` means white space at the end of the string. `\s` includes tab too (\t) If you need only space use: `/ $/`

**JavaScript**

```
var myStr = "some random string ";

if(/\s$/.test(myStr)) {
   // string contains space at last
} else {
   //string does not contain space at last
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.prototype.substr(start, from)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
var str = "lego ";
str.substr(str.length-1, str.length-2)===" "
> true
```

Or even better use [String.prototype.endsWith(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```
var str = "lego ";
str.endsWith(" ");
> true
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input ng-model="vm.value" ng-change="vm.onChange()">
```

JS

```
vm.value = '';

vm.counter = 0;

vm.onChange = function () {
    if (vm.value[vm.value.length - 1] === ' ') {
        vm.counter++;
    }
};
```

Comment: it does only works when ng-trim is set to false(I need to use this as a true), but then I dont have to write this kind of counter cuz all spaces are counted.

Comment: if `ng-trim` is true then you will never have spaces at the end of the value